# Integration : $\int 2x(x^2+2)^{\frac32}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integration : $\displaystyle\int 2x(x^2+2)^{\frac32}\ dx$

......
$$=\int 2x(x^2+2)^{\frac32}\ dx$$
$$=2\int x(x^2+2)^{^{\frac32}}\ dx$$
Let $x^2=y$. Now,
$$=2\int \sqrt {y} (y+2)^{^{\frac32}}\ dy$$
....

Comment: How about $$\sqrt{x^2+2}=u\implies x^2+2=u^2$$

Comment: Just let $u = x^{2} + 2$ from the start. Then your integration amounts to finding the primitive of $u^{3/2}$.

Comment: You have forgotten the $dx$. Without this, a substitution will give the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x^2+2=z^2,\implies2xdx=2zdz$ and $\left(x^2+2\right)^{3/2}=z^3$.

So, 
\begin{align*}
\int 2x(x^2+2)^{\frac32}\ dx&=\int z^3\cdot2z\ dz\\
&=2\int z^4\ dz\\
&=\dfrac{2}{5}z^5+c\hspace{25pt}\text{[where, c=integration const.]}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{5}\left(x^2+2\right)^{\frac52}+c
\end{align*}
Or, without assuming anything you can do as:

$$\int2x(x^2+2)^{\frac32}\ dx=\int(x^2+2)^{\frac32}\ d(x^2+2)=\dfrac{1}{1+\frac32}(x^2+2)^{1+\frac32}+c=\dfrac{2}{5}\left(x^2+2\right)^{\frac52}+c$$

Answer (score 3):

What everyone is implicitly saying is that you've made a mistake. You're first equality is fine, but in your second one, because you've not been writing "$dx$" or "$dy$", you've forgotten to divide by the derivative. So you let $x^2 = y$, but then didn't then say "$dy = 2 x dx$". As such, you're supposed to have
$$ \int 2x (x^2 + 3)^{3/2} dx = \int 2x (x^2 + 3)^{3/2} \frac1{2x} dy = \int (y+3)^{3/2} dy. $$
You can then use the normal rules to say that this final integral equals
$$ \tfrac25(y+3)^{5/2} + \text{constant} = \tfrac25 (x^2 + 3)^{5/2} + \text{constant}. $$

While the other answers are 100% correct, hopefully this enlightens you as to your mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

$$y = x^2 +2$$
$$dy = 2x \ dx$$

$$I = \int dy \ y^\frac{3}{2} = \frac{2}{5} y^\frac{5}{2} +C = (x^2 +2)^\frac{5}{2} +C $$

Comment: How is $\textrm {dy}=2x \textrm {dx}$?

Comment: @Aryabhatta $dy/dx = 2x$

Comment: @SpineFast, How is $$I=\int dy  y^{\dfrac {3}{2}}=\dfrac {2}{5} y^{\dfrac {5}{2}} + C$$?

Comment: @Aryabhatta $\int dy \ y^r = y^{r+1}/(r+1) +C$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

use the substitution
$$
x^2+2=u \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad  2xdx=du
$$